# ping server in namespace from remote machine

Tags: network-namespace

If I run web server in default namespace of `SERVER` machine I can `curl` it from `REMOTE` machine doing that:

```
curl http://SERVER:80/
```

Now I put web server in namespace `nested` with providing `veth` peered with `nested's` network interface:

```
sudo ip link add veth type veth peer name vpeer
sudo ip link set vpeer netns nested
sudo ip addr add 192.168.3.77/24 dev veth
sudo ip link set veth up
sudo ip netns exec nested ip addr add 192.168.3.78/24 dev vpeer
sudo ip netns exec nested ip link set vpeer up
sudo ip netns exec nested ip route add default via 192.168.3.77
```

so I can ping it from default namespace:

```
curl --interface veth 192.168.3.78:80/
```

My question: how to ping web server in `nested` namespace from remote machine?
Seems that `curl http://SERVER:80/` becomes to `lo` interface. Can I point external requests to `veth` interface or how to configure pairing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The remote host must have a route to the nested namespace ip address (`192.168.3.78`). The routing setup depends on many factors.
2. The ip forwarding should be enabled in the default namespace (sysctl variable `net.ipv4.ip_forward` should be `1`).
3. The firewall should allow the forwarded packets between the `veth` and lan interfaces. At result you should have a success ping between the remote host and the nested namespace.
4. If the `SERVER` domain name points to one of local ip addresses, you should use the `DNAT` target to redirect the request into the netsted namespace:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 --dst <orig-ip> -j DNAT --to 192.168.3.78
iptables -t nat -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 --dst <orig-ip> -j DNAT --to 192.168.3.78
```

5. Use the tcpdump to troubleshoot issues.

Comment: Thank you! It helped! Can't mark it as Solution because don't have enough reputation.